# Маршрутизация и костыли

Tags: маршрутизация

Ситуация: есть сервер на нем eth0(192.168.0.1), eth2(192.168.1.1). Оба интерфейса являются по умолчанию шлюзами для своих сеток. ip_forward включен. Клиенты подсеток видят друг друга.
Дополнительно: на этом же сервере поднят тунель 10.8.0.6->10.8.0.5(на том конце туннеля удаленная машина из подсетки имеет ip - 192.168.21.26).
В route на машине 192.168.21.26 прописан обратный маршрут для моей локальной подсетки 192.168.0.1. (то есть я получаю нормальный ответ на пинг от 192.168.21.26 через тунель, если смотреть через tcpdump). Однако подсетка 192.168.1.1 на том конце туннеля не прописана и возможности прописать ее там нету, ибо такая сетка уже существует на том конце.

Надо добиться получения ответов от удаленной машины через тунель для подсетки 192.168.1.1.

Как этого добится? Пустить весь трафик через 192.168.0.1? Или что?

Comment: никак. вот я находясь в той сети запускаю ping 192.168.1.2, к какому 1.2 я обращаюсь, который в моей сети или который за туннелем ? единственное решение в такой ситуации это NAT, в котором будет четко задано какие адреса в какие надо превращать. что бы в собранной вместе сети все адреса были уникальными. (P.S. подсетки 192.168.1.1 не существует в природе, это ip конкретной машины)

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответ, но вообще как Вы бы решили эту задачу, если она возникла бы у Вас? Вообще эта задача решаема в описанных условий или нет?

Comment: Надо плясать от того есть ли хоть одна машина в первой сети, которая будет нужна во второй и при этом во второй есть машина с тем же ip. Если да - то значит ее адрес надо для второй сети представить каким нибудь другим, т.е. выполнить NAT скажем 192.168.1.2 превратить в 192.168.10.2. Когда клиенту понадобится машина из другой сети он должен послать запрос явно на 192.168.10.2, а ближайший к нему роутер, видя что это некая 10 подсеть перешлет пакет второму, тот поменяет ip отправителя на свой (что бы ответ пришел), и ip назначения на 192.168.1.2

Comment: Если же нужны всего несколько ip и они в принципе уникальны, т.е. в другой сети не найдется машин с теми же ip, то тогда я бы включил proxy arp и прописал маршрутизацию на конкретные ip, которые нужны. И когда клиент начнет искать в своей сети машину 192.168.1.2 (которой тут нет, но она есть в другой сети), то на его arp-запрос ответит сам роутер, после чего клиент весь трафик для нее пришлет роутеру и тот будет пересылать его в туннель, при этом заменив адрес отправителя на свой, что бы во второй сети не было проблем с доставкой ответа

Comment: В целом ясно, добавлю для более ясного понимания, сетка 192.168.0.1 прописана в таблице маршрутов на той стороне туннеля, значит мне надо перенаправить весь трафик от сети 192.168.1.0 на 192.168.0.1 и включить NAT чтобы получить нормальный ответ от машины на той стороне туннеля?

Comment: Ну и сказать клиентам, что бы обращались к 192.168.10.x для машин другой стороны. Основа всего такова: когда клиенту надо отправить пакет, то первым делом он смотрит по своим настройкам в какой он сети и если ip точки назначения попадает в его сеть (с учетом маски подсети), то он кидает в свою сеть arp-запрос "кто тут 192.168.1.x", та машина ему отвечает, он узнает ее MAC и шлет пакеты ей на прямую. Если же машина не в его сети он смотрит в таблицу маршрутизации и шлет пакет маршрутизатору. Значит он либо сразу должен понять что машина не у него, либо маршрутизатор должен сделать arp proxy

Answer (score 1):

Основной принцип маршрутизации в локальных сетях - если удаленный адрес находится в сети, которая прямо подключена к интерфейсу, то для получения не нужен маршрутизатор. Группа адресов которые должна считаться локально достижимыми описывается маской сети.

Только если адрес компьютера не попадает в группу локально достижимых адресов ip-пакет будет переслан шлюзу, а шлюз выбран соответственно таблице маршрутизации.

Возможно поделить сеть 192.168.1.0/24 на несколько сетей: 192.168.1.0/25 + 192.168.1.128/25 или 192.168.1.0/26 + 192.168.1.64/26 + 192.168.1.128/26 + 192.168.1.195/26. В них будет меньше места, но можно будет сделать нормальную маршрутизацию. Хотя по затратам труда наверное больше чем изменить адресацию у одной из сетей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можно привести пример описанного Вами решения с примерами путей в таблице маршрутизации. Просто что-то не соображу, как разбить сетку на подсети имея всего один физичсеский интерфейс (или добавить алиасы)?

Comment: кстати, если нет возможности оперировать с адресами сетей, то можно ведь поднять альтернативные сети. т.е. в обоих локациях с одинаковыми адресами поднять вторые сети с разными адресами. например сети 192.168.100.0/24 и 192.168.200.0/24 на сервере алиасы соответствующие 192.168.100.1 и 192.168.200.1 и по второму ip адресу у нужных хостов. В таком случае можно будет делать запросы к адресам из разных подсетей. Нужна будет запись в маршрутах хостов чтобы выбрать шлюзом не маршрут по умолчанию, но не нужен будет nat